# How to solve the recurrence $T(n) = T\left(\lceil\frac{n}{\sqrt{2}}\rceil+1\right) + 1$?

Tags: recurrence-relations

How to solve the recurrence $T(n) = T\left(\lceil\frac{n}{\sqrt{2}}\rceil+1\right) + 1,\ T(n) = 1$ for $n \leq 8$?

Ignoring the ceil and using the Master Theorem I have
$$a = 1,\ b = \sqrt{2},\ log_b(a) = log_\sqrt{2}(1) = 0,\ w(n) = 1$$
So we are in case 2:
$$w(n) = \Theta(n^{log_b(a)})$$
and then
$$T(n) = \Theta\left(log(n)\right)$$
I know from [Wolfram Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=T%28n%29%3D1%2BT%28n%2Fsqrt%282%29%2B1%29%2C+T%288%29%3D1) that exists a more precise estimation
$$T(n) \approx 2\cdot log_2(n)$$
How can I achieve this?

Comment: Your (presumably integer) recurrence isn't well-defined as written; do you mean $T(n)=T\left(\left\lfloor\frac n{\sqrt{2}}\right\rfloor+1\right)+1$?

Comment: @StevenStadnicki You're right, I was solving the same but with ceil:
$T(n)=T\left(\left\lceil\frac n{\sqrt{2}}\right\rceil+1\right)+1$

Comment: The answer shouldn't be sensitive to the difference in a case like this, fortunately, but I wanted to call it out explicitly.

Comment: @StevenStadnicki I have found that in the context of solving recursive equations for algorithmic complexities, in particular with the master theorem, one usually does not bother with such floors and ceilings. It is entirely conventional to forgo them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An attempt to justify the Wolfram Alpha result.

As

$$
T\left(\gamma^{\log_{\gamma}n}\right)=T\left(\gamma^{\log_{\gamma}\left(\frac{n}{\gamma}\right)}+1\right)+1
$$

now assuming $n \ge N$ and $\gamma^{\log_{\gamma}\left(\frac{N}{\gamma}\right)}>> 1$ making $\mathbb{T}\left(\cdot\right)=T\left(\gamma^{(\cdot)}\right)$ and $z = \log_{\gamma}n$ we follow with

$$
\mathbb{T}\left(z\right)=\mathbb{T}\left(z-1\right)+1
$$

with solution

$$
\mathbb{T}\left(z\right)=z+c_0
$$

and now going backwards with $z = \log_{\gamma}n$ we get at

$$
T(n) \approx \log_{\gamma}n + c_0
$$

and considering $\gamma = \sqrt{2}$

$$
T(n) \approx 2\log_2 n
$$

Comment: That's an interesting transform, thanks!